# How to add fills and short sections in FL Studio?

Tags: fl-studio

Let me explain. In fl studio in both the piano roll and the playlist view every 16 beats the colours switch between grey and a lighter grey alternatively if you have a 4/4 time signature. With a lot of music though you often end up having a fill between two parts that only lasts 1 beat or 4 beats or whatever and then your whole song after that is out of sync with those coloured sections. Obviously it doesn't really matter but I've always wondered if there is a way to fix this? I would have googled it but I wouldn't know what to google really, didn't even know what to put as the title to this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> you open up the Time Marker tab, and you can change the time signature there, so if you want a fill that lasts an extra two beats, you can make just that one measure a 6/4 (or add an extra 2/4 measure) and then everything will remain in sync.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got the question right, but here is my answer : 
Simply put your fill on the last beat or so of your part, so nothing is out of sync, that's what I usually do, and that's what most people I know do too. Hope this helped.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean but I actually found the answer to my own question. 
It is in this video at 1:04 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQ4M-MNLUtA
You can see at 1:37 what happens in FL is EXACTLY what I wanted :) I can't be bothered writing out the instructions though.